# How to get number of parts from STL file?

Tags: c#

I have an binary format STL (STereoLithography) file, I have successfully read the file from c#.net and got the facets, I also got the count of triangles, volume of the part and surface area of the part and dimensions of the 3D object(Length,breadth,height). But now the problem is that I am not able to find the number of parts and layer thickness . Please help.

Comment: Maybe you can supply some code. What do you mean with "not being able to find"? Is your file incomplete?

Comment: Have you looked at the file format documentation? http://www.ennex.com/~fabbers/StL.asp.

Comment: I have tried the documentations, but did not find any thing about the parts in STL file.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies to the people who designed the binary STL format, but to me it seems a little ugly.

A summary of the format is an 80 byte header, followed by a dword (number of triangles), then each triangle stored with Normal, Vertex1,2&3 stored as x,y,z in single floating point format followed by a 16 bit short (0) - this repeating until end of file.

There is no differentiation between objects which means that essentially programs that interpret the file must internally keep a list of all vertexes, removing duplicates as they go so as to have a proper 'manifold' body (If that's important I suppose).

Should you wish to break it up into multiple objects you'd have to essentially look for 'islands' of faces - finding all faces that relate to each other by virtue of sharing a vertex. The separate objects would be the clumps that don't relate to each other.

As far as I'm aware, the standard STL format does not include things like layer thickness - if you're talking about 3D printing slice thickness, then the STL is the step prior to slicing - so doesn't have a 'layer thickness' per se.

I'm sure you wanted an easier answer but if there is, then I haven't found it :)